# Delegate Data Not Being Passed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a problem where data isn't getting passed over by my delegate and I know why, but I don't know how to resolve it.

I have a view controller with a subview which passes data back to the view controller via a delegate. Simple things such as floats. While that subview is getting data, if I for example bring up another view controller such as a `UIImagePickerController` and then dismiss that going back to the original view controller, the delegate will have failed to pass its data while that child view controller is displayed.

Any ideas as to how I can solve this? It seems the delegate just won't function in the background.

Thanks.

Further Explanation:

The code won't be too revealing, its very standard. But allow me to explain further.

• Load `UITableViewController`

• This controller has a cell with a subclassed `UIView` in it.

• I have a lot of code so I put it into a subclass vs directly the table.

• This view needs to change height depending on content.

• Once it has retrieved its data, via a bog stander delegate method, I send a float to the parent `UITableViewController`.

• When that float is sent, I update the cell height of the table (the float being the new height).

• This works!

• However, if I present my `UIImagePickerController` before the table has updated, it never receives the data.

• While the picker is present, the delegate never sends the data. If it is not present, it will send the data just fine.

Comment: Please post your code, can't help much without it

Comment: show the code please :)

Comment: A hidden subview passes data to a delegate?

Comment: I've updated with a little more detail which hopefully explains things.

Comment: Some code would be nice.  Just strip out anything you deem sensitive.

Comment: When you bring up another viewController do you perhaps dismiss the viewController you experiencing the problems with? Have you tried putting a breakpoint in dealloc to see if it's called or logging self to see if it's the same instance you're returning to?

Comment: Are the properties of your UIView subclass all strong? If not it maybe that it releases the information when you present a new view controller (such as the picker..)

Comment: Well the CGFloat I am passing is declared with assign, but I can't declare it with strong as its a float.

Comment: @Jeff, my question seems to be similar and is explained using code. If you can spare a moment please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/44969276/2348597. Thanks