# In ObjectiveC using delegate how do I send a message without using a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, selector

I recently learned to use delegates to send messages from one class to another whenever a button is pressed and I'd like to find out how to send a message without a button action. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418764-performselector?language=objc) suggests a likely method is `performSelector:(SEL)aSelector;` but I had no luck when I tried to use it. Instead, this is what I tried.

In **MicroTune.h**, I defined a delegate and gave it a property

```
    @class Synth;

    @protocol TuningDelegate <NSObject>
        -(void)setTuning:(NSData *)tuningData;
    @end

    @interface MicroTune : NSObject
        {
        …
        }

    @property (assign) id<TuningDelegate> delegate;
    @end
```

In **Synth.h**, I declared the class so it acts as a delegate

```
    #import "MicroTune.h"

    @interface Synth : NSObject <TuningDelegate>
```

and in **Synth.m**, I created a method to let me know the message arrived

```
    #import "Synth.h"

    - (void)setTuning:(NSData *)tuningData
    {
        NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tuningData];
        NSLog(@" hip hip %@", array);
    }
```

*EDIT*

---

And, also in Synth.m, to make sure the delegate is recognised, I added the following

```
    - (id)initWithSampleRate:(float)sampleRate_ 
        { if ((self = [super init])) 
            { 
                microTuneClassObject.delegate = self;

                // etc. etc.

            } return self; 
        }
                    (Use of undeclared identifier 'microTuneClassObject')
```

*and also tried*

```
    MicroTune.delegate = self;
        (Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'MicroTune')
```

*and*

```
    self.MicroTune.delegate = self;
        (Property 'MicroTune' not found on object of type 'Synth *')
```

---

And finally, in **MicroTune.m**, I defined a method to send the message

```
    #import "MicroTune.h"

    - (void)sendTuning:(NSData *)tuningData 
    {
        [synthLock lock];
        [self.delegate setTuning:(NSData *)tuningData];
        [synthLock unlock];
    }
```

but Xcode gave the following message.

> ```
>       No type or protocol named 'TuningDelegate'
> ```

Can someone kindly explain what I need to do to send the message ? Thanks.

---

CONCLUSION

The solution can be found in my supplementary answer.

Comment: Did you `#import` the .h file in Synth.m?

Comment: Did you include `MicroTune.h` in `Synth.h`?

Comment: Paulw11 & mag_zbc, yes. I checked before making the latest edits.

Comment: your code works fine for me. Make sure you are setting the delegate property to a Synth reference.

Comment: @user3752049, did you mean a line in synth.m implementation like self.MicroTune.delegate = self; ? (see the latest edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MicroTune.h` file,

instead of `#import "Synth.h"` write `@class Synth`

Comment: @Greg why are you importing ` #import "Synth.h"` in `MicroTune.h` ?

Comment: @Greg in `MicroTune.h` instead of `import "Synth.h"` try `@class Synth`.

Comment: Shailesh, I tried that and also reverted to the original state of MicroTune.h (as per your answer). No change.

Comment: @Greg remove import `Synth.h` from `MicroTune.h` file  if you are not using it in MicroTune.h file or explain the purpose of that import

Comment: Shailesh, I've restored the change you suggested because it  shows the direction of communication between MicroTune and Synth correctly

Comment: `microTuneClassObject.delegate =self` in `Synth.m` file ,have u done this anywhere?

Comment: `microTuneClassObject.delegate =self` line is important , so that `Synth.m` class will listen for `[self.delegate setTuning:(NSData *)tuningData]; ` method to get fire in `MicroTune` class.As soon as it will get fired, `- (void)setTuning:(NSData *)tuningData{}` will be updated in `Synth class`.

Comment: Shailesh, (after a sleep) I tried     - (id)initWithSampleRate:(float)sampleRate_
    {
     if ((self = [super init]))
     {
            MicroTune.delegate = self;  // etc. etc.        
     }
     return self;
    }

Comment: Shailesh, your comments turned out to be 100% accurate. Thanks for your help. I’ve accepted your answer. The solution is to make the forward declaration to MicroTune from Synth - I had it the other way round. You'll find a full explanation in my supplementary answer.

Answer (score 0):

In **Synth.h**

```
    @class MicroTune;

    @interface Synth : NSObject
    {
        MicroTune      *setTuning;
    }

    - (MicroTune*)setTuning;
```

In **Synth.m**

```
    #import "Synth.h"
    #import "MicroTune.h"
```

and from Synth.m, tuning data is retrieved from MicroTune *(when the PlayViewController sends a MIDI Program Change message)*

```
    - (void)sendProgramChange:(uint8_t)oneOfFiveFamilies
            onChannel:(uint8_t)oneOfSixteenPlayers
    {
        uint8_t tuningTransposition     = oneOfFiveFamilies;
        uint8_t assignedPitches         = oneOfSixteenPlayers;

        MicroTune *dekany               = [[MicroTune alloc] init];

    // send a 2-byte "MIDI event" to fetch archived tuning data

        id archivedArray                = [dekany sendMIDIEvent:(uint8_t)tuningTransposition
                                                  data1:(uint8_t)assignedPitches];

        NSArray *array                  = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedArray];

        NSLog(@"\n%@", array);

        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        {
            NSNumber *num               = array[i];
            float hertz                 = [num floatValue];
            _pitches[i]                 = hertz;
        }
    }
```